# Approximating $AB$ by $AP$ where $P$ is an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection, projection-matrices

Let $A\in {R} ^{m \times d}$, $B \in R^{d \times d}$. Given $n\leq d$, I want to find an orthogonal projection $P$ onto an $n$-dimensional subspace of $R^d$ s.t $AP$ best approximates $AB$ according to some reasonable measure of approximation. Does this problem have a closed form solution?

Comment: The problem is not well defined until you will have defined your "reasonable measure of approximation"

Comment: I agree, but I don’t have something particular in mind, and wanted to know if a similar problem is known. If this helps, I think some matrix norm can be a natural choice, e.g. minimising $||AP-AB||$ under Frobenius norm.